# How can I prevent my React app from crashing when using useSWR in layout.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have the following code where `useSWR` crashes react the`layout.tsx` component.

```
"use client";

import {
  BellIcon,
  EllipsisHorizontalCircleIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  UsersIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import "./globals.css";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import { Suspense, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from "@/components/Button";
import Image from "next/image";
import Loading from "@/components/Loading";

const font = Poppins({ subsets: ["latin"], weight: "500" });

const fetcher = (url: any) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

const MAIN_WIDTH = 700;

export const RootContext = createContext<any>(null);

export type User = {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  lastSeen: Date;
  email: string;
  photoURL: string | null;
  bio: string;
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
    `/api/getUser?email=${10}`,
    fetcher
  );
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{suspense: true}}>
    <Suspense fallback={<p>loading...</p>}>
      <RootContext.Provider value={{ user: [user, setUser] }}>
        <html lang="en">
          <body className={font.className}>
            <div className={`w-[calc((100vw-600px)*0.5)] h-screen p-8`}>
              <div className="flex flex-col h-full justify-between items-end">
                <></>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2 items-end">
                  <div className="icon px-4 py-3 items-center flex space-x-4 w-[250px]">
                    <HomeIcon className="w-7 h-7" />
                    <h1 className="text-xl">Home</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon px-4 py-3 items-center flex space-x-4 w-[250px]">
                    <UsersIcon className="w-7 h-7" />
                    <h1 className="text-xl">Users</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon p-4 py-3 items-center flex space-x-4 w-[250px]">
                    <BellIcon className="w-7 h-7" />
                    <h1 className="text-xl">Notifications</h1>
                  </div>

                  <Button />
                </div>

                {user && (
                  <div className="w-[250px] icon items-center flex space-x-4">
                    <Image
                      className="rounded-full"
                      src={user?.photoURL as string}
                      height={50}
                      width={50}
                      alt="User Image"
                    />
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                      <h1>{user?.name?.substring(0, 12)}</h1>
                      <p className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">
                        @{user?.username?.toLowerCase()?.substring(0, 12)}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <EllipsisHorizontalCircleIcon className="w-6 h-6 text-neutral-500" />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-[600px] noScrollbar h-screen overflow-auto border-x border-neutral-200">
              {children}
              <div className="h-[160px]"></div>
            </div>
            <div className={`w-[calc((100vw-600px)*0.5)] h-screen p-8`}>
              <div className="p-4 bg-neutral-100 rounded-xl">
                <h1 className="text-xl">Who to follow</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </RootContext.Provider>
    </Suspense>
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
```

Everytime I add a useSWR fetch to `/api/getUser` the entire app crashes and is frozen but whenever I remove it is stays fine. Also, this error is only happening in the layout.tsx, all useSWRs in other files work.